# Using form_for and form_tag whilst still passing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, form-for

This is probably an easy one but looking for some clarification so i can understand what is happening. I am using stripe to make a payment and have set up a form using form_tag

```
<%= form_tag donations_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>

<%= text_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: "Email Address", class: 'form-control', :data => {:stripe => 'email' } %>

<%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :placeholder => "Card Number",  class: 'form-control', :data => {:stripe => 'number' } %>

 <!--More fields here-->

<% end %>
```

Now when submitting this form via this controller

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create

@amount = params[:donation_amount].to_i
# Create the Customer Object 
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => params[:email],
  :card  => params[:stripeToken]
)

charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
:customer    => customer.id,
:amount      => @amount,
:description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
:currency    => 'usd'
)

 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:error] = e.message
   redirect_to donations_path
 end


private

 def donation_params
  params.require(:donation).permit(:id, :campaign_id, :name, :email, :message, :donation_amount)
end
end
```

The params passed are

```
authenticity_token  randomtokenhere
email   richlewis14@gmail.com   
stripeToken tok_104HXi4DL3s6WpXhX5bTCxMW
utf8    ✓
```

if i change my form to a form_for and use the following form, the stripeToken is no longer generated

```
authenticity_token  randomtokenhere
email   richlewis14@gmail.com   
utf8    ✓
```

and i am wondering how i can get this to work

NEW FORM

```
<%= form_for @donation, id: 'payment-form' do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email Address", class: 'form-control', :data => {:stripe => 'email' } %>

<%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :placeholder => "Card Number",  class: 'form-control', :data => {:stripe => 'number' } %>

 <!--More fields here-->

<% end %>
```

NEW Controller

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @donation = Donation.new
end

def create
@dontation = Donation.new(donation_params)
@amount = params[:donation][:donation_amount].to_i
# Create the Customer Object 
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => params[:donation][:email],
  :card  => params[:stripeToken]
)

charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
:customer    => customer.id,
:amount      => @amount,
:description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
:currency    => 'usd'
)

 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:error] = e.message
   redirect_to donations_path
 end


private

 def donation_params
  params.require(:donation).permit(:id, :campaign_id, :name, :email, :message, :donation_amount)
end
end
```

Im missing something simple im sure but if anyone can point out what that would be much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not mention that, but I guess the `stripeToken` is added by some javascript that relies on finding the `form#payment-form`, right?

So your error might be, that your second `form` does not get the right id.

When using `form_for` you have to pass html attributes like this:

```
<%= form_for @donation, html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

PS: There is a typo in your second controllers 'create' method (`@dontation` instead of `@donation`)

Comment: you where totally correct, my form did not have the correct id, thank you for spotting that... token now generated :-)

Comment: Be extra careful about your form fields this way—one slip-up in forgetting to `nil` a field name and the PCI monster comes to get you. ;)

Comment: @colinm huh? you mean me? or what? dont get it :)

Comment: @colinm could you explain a bit more please

Comment: @Richlewis If any of the card information fields have a valid `name` attribute (e.g. you accidentally use `f.text_field` or pass a name on a `text_field_tag`), they will be transmitted to your server and you will be in PCI-DSS scope. While there was also this potential in your original code, `form_for` flips a switch in many developers' heads and suddenly you've got `f.text_field :card_number`. (Some refactoring tools will also encourage this error by complaining about your mixed field tags.)

Comment: @colinm interesting point. Not necessary to slip with the ruby code, even switched-off javascript on client side would lead to card-info be submitted to the server.. Is that really the recommended architecture for swipe? I wonder if it wouldnt be wiser to have the sensible input fields outside of the form that is submitted to my server.. Never worked with swipe though, just thinking loudly..

Comment: @colinm thank you for bringing in this up, to help me and others who see this post would you mind providing an example of how you would set up your form or how you would handle this..it would be much appreciated, thanks